# PropertyDescriptor.getReadMethod() tries to find set method instead of get method

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class:

```
public abstract class Produkt extends ObjectPlus implements Serializable {
    static int ID = 0;
    private int id;

    public Produkt() {
        super();
        id = ID++;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    //lot OF OTHER METHODS
}
```

Somewhere else in other class I try to invoke `getId()` method on an object to get the `id` field value by this:

`Integer fieldValue =  (Integer) new PropertyDescriptor("Id", c).getReadMethod().invoke(o);`

`c` is of type `Class`, `o` is of type `Object`, `id` is the field I want.

but I get this exception:

```
java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setId
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at pakiet.ObjectPlus.getCurrentId(ObjectPlus.java:143)
    at pakiet.ObjectPlus.wczytajEkstensje(ObjectPlus.java:118)
    at pakiet.Main.main(Main.java:72)
```

### Why does he try access setter instead of getter?

The full method is:

```
public static int getCurrentId(Class c){
        //jak wczytamy to zeby nowe osoby mialy nadal unikalne ID(wieksze od najwiekszego)
        int maxId = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Map.Entry<Class, ArrayList> entry : ekstensje.entrySet()) {
            for (Object o : entry.getValue()){
                // This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator.
                if(c.isInstance(o)){
                    try{
                     Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
                     Integer fieldValue =  (Integer) new PropertyDescriptor("Id", c).getReadMethod().invoke(o);

                    if(fieldValue > maxId)
                        maxId = fieldValue;

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return maxId + 1;
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that your PropertyDescriptor constructor takes your string "Id" and attempts to find a `setId()` to use because of it, and that there is no such method for it to call.

EDIT: that's exactly what's happening: check out the source code for [PropertyDescriptor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.java)

Comment: Yes, I know it. The exception message is explicit. I wanted to access `getId()` instead `setId()`, that is why I use `getReadMethod()`, not `getWriteMethod()` but Java is stubborn and tries to access `setId()`.

Comment: But you cannot create a PropertyDescriptor object unless the target contains both a getter and a setter for the value; you are welcome to access either one you want, but both must exist *if you use the constructor in that form*.  There are other constructors for PropertyDescriptor, and some of them not only allow you to specify the get/set methods used, but allow you to specify null for one of them if the property doesn't have that access.  You could use one of those, perhaps.

Comment: The other constructors are (sadly) not suitable for this use case, as you'd need to know the name of the getter beforehand, which is exactly why one would use the PropertyDescriptor in the first place. I don't think there's a solution to this other than doing the method searching yourself (with prefixes "get" and "is").

Comment: Doesn't the getter have to be `getId()`? You know the name of the field, why doesn't that give you the name of the getter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different constructor for this purpose, although it's not as clean (you could however wrap it into a helper function):

```
Method getter = new PropertyDescriptor(property, objectClass, "is" + Character.toUpperCase(property.charAt(0)) + property.substring(1), null).getReadMethod();
```

Although I'm passing the "is" prefix, this also works for properties with a getter starting with "get". If there is no "is" method then getReadMethod will search for one named "get".